# Closure of the interior of a convex set in a topological vector space

Tags: gn.general-topology, convex-geometry, topological-vector-spaces

Let $C$ be a convex set with nonempty interior in a topological vector space. Do we always have :
$\overline {C^\circ} = \overline{C}$ ?

If not, what is the "minimal" condition on the space so that this equality is true?

Comment: Cf. Bourbaki, EVT II.2.6, Proposition 16 Corollaire 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Assume WLOG that $0$ is an interior point and $y$ is in $C$.  Draw a picture to see that the interval $[0,y)$ is contained in the interior of $C$.  Specifically, if $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$ contained in $C$ and $0<s<1$, then $sy + (1-s) U \subset C$.